# What is the best way to change the “style” of your voice entirely?

Tags: voice

I am a 20 year old female. The only singing experience I have outside my car is in a choir where I sang soprano. However, I have stopped singing since then and I’m a decent alto.

However, when I try and sing now, friends and family tell me that my head voice is too breathy and nasally, and my chest voice sounds like I’m trying to hard to sound “good”. I have a great range and pretty good control, but no one likes the style of my voice. People call it annoying. And I know I sing on key.

Would I be better off trying to mimic other styles within my range? Just focus on chest voice (or head voice)? Is it a confidence thing? How can I improve my current voice, or how can I adopt a new style all together?

Comment: First I I would ask how do *you* feel and hear yourself when singing. Do you feel comfortable? Do you like it? Are you actually trying to sound like a specific style or singer? Other people's opinions and perceptions are as biased as our own. I guess Janis Joplin singing could be for some be perceived as "annoying" for example.

Comment: You need initially to record your voice(s). Just listening to yourself sing won't give you a fair indication of what it actually sounds like.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest seeing a singing teacher, if you can find one.  (You might find one or two sessions enough to point you in the right direction, or if it goes well you might enjoy taking regular lessons.)

Both breathiness and a nasal quality could result from not engaging or balancing the different resonances, and that's something that's hard to learn without someone there to show you what to do and give you direct feedback.

(I took lessons for several years; it surprised me how much *technical* stuff there was to learn.  After all, we use our voices every day, and most of us have been able to sing since we were small!  But the voice is at least as complex an instrument as most others — everyone's is slightly different, and you can't see it, nor accurately hear it, making it a harder to learn to a good standard than you might think.  So a good teacher is invaluable.)